# How to speed up foreach and post value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, foreach

I use MVC4 and I have a big problem.

cshtml code:

```
@{
    int degersayac = 0;
    Object[] degerler = { item3.AKS, item3.AOS, item3.AZS, item3.IKS, item3.IOS, item3.IZS, item3.PKS, item3.POS, item3.PZS };
}
@foreach (var item4 in new[] { "Anımsama", "İşlevsel", "Program" })
{
    foreach (var item5 in new[] { "Kolay", "Orta", "Zor" })
    {
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("veri[" + sayac + "].soruAdeti", 0,
                new
                {
                    Style = "width:100%",
                    data_val = "true",
                    data_val_required = "No. of joinees is required",
                    data_val_number = "The field No. of joinees must be a number.",
                    data_val_range = "No. of joinees should be minimum 2 and not more than 10",
                    data_val_range_max = "10",
                    data_val_range_min = "0",
                 }
             )
             @Html.Hidden("veri[" + sayac + "].BO_ID", item3.BO_ID)
             @Html.Hidden("veri[" + sayac + "].Zorluk", item5)
             @Html.Hidden("veri[" + sayac + "].Duzey", item4)
             @{sayac++; degersayac++;}
        </td>
    }
}
```

this two foreach in other foreach like

```
@foreach(var item in model)
{
}
```

Model in entityframework. Model will have over 1000 record and I should create `record * 9` textboxes and `record * 3 * 9` hidden values.

However this page is open too slow :(

And this page posts maybe 12,000 values to other action. This takes too long (over 15 seconds) and crashes page alert (page is crashed, close page or wait) from chrome browser.
If I wait, page is load but I don't want wait too second.

Comment: Why would your client need to edit 12,000 items at a time?

Comment: because, I will create list all attribute for user
and user select value for all attribute and post other page

Comment: can I try model edit.
I add, `public Nullable<int> valuee { get; set; }`
and try post my model, but I cant post `@model IEnumerable<mymodel>`